# Jquery class attribute navigation

Tags: jquery, class

I'm trying to build a very simple VPS control panel; i have the following code that lists every VPS i have on a particular server :

($active variable is a BOOLEAN giving the current state of the VPS)

```
<ul id="vps">
<li <? if ($active): ?>class="active"<? endif;?> >
<? if ($active): ?>
   <div class="status">running</div>
   <?else:?>
   <div class="status">halted</div>
<? endif; ?>

<div class="sub">
  <div class="activity">
  <? if ($active): ?>
      <a href="#" id="<?=$vpsid?>" class="activevps"><img src="stop.png" /></a>
  <? else: ?>
    <a href="#" id="<?=$vpsid?>" class="desactivevps"><img src="start.png"/></a>
  <? endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following JQuery actions :

```
<script>
    $('.activevps').click(function(e){ 
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).html ('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
        var source = $(this);
        var tt = new Date().getTime();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/vpsadmin/stop/' + tt,
          data: 'vps='+target,
          dataType: "html", 
          timeout: (60 * 1000), 
          success: function(data) {
          $('.vps_'+target).html ('<a href="#" id="'+target+'" class="desactivevps"><img src="play.png" /></a>');
        },
          error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){alert(strError);
    }
    });
```

and same code for STOP action

```
<script>
    $('.desactivevps').click(function(e){ 
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).html ('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
        var source = $(this);
        var tt = new Date().getTime();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/vpsadmin/start/' + tt,
          data: 'vps='+target,
          dataType: "html", 
          timeout: (60 * 1000), 
          success: function(data) {
          $('.vps_'+target).html ('<a href="#" id="'+target+'" class="activevps"><img src="stop.png" /></a>');
        },
          error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){alert(strError);
    }
    });
```

I'm looking forward to do some actions here (but lost in jquery actions).

- When clicking on the **start/stop** icon; it should trigger the ajax post and :
- Change the **'li'** class to 'inactive'
- Change the **'status'** class to 'halted' or 'running'
- Change the **'a'** class to activevps/desactivevps and also change the img src associated.

I'm quite new to Jquery; how to do all this using the simple click function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw a sample together on jsFiddle that I think helps you out.  Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MuZMs/1/).

Basically, the code you posted is pretty close - I just had to make a few adjustments.

### HTML Markup

```
<ul id="vps">
<li class="active" >
   <div class="status">running</div>

  <div class="sub">
    <div class="activity">
      <a href="#" id="100" class="activevps"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Icons-mini-action_stop.gif" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The only change I made here was cosmetic (changed the image URL to something I could read on jsFiddle) and I also closed the `<li>` and `<ul>` tags.

### jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.activevps').click(function(e){         
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
        var source = $(this);
        var tt = new Date().getTime();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/ajax_json_echo/?q=' + tt,
          data: 'vps='+target,
          dataType: "html",
          timeout: (60 * 1000),
          context: $(this),  //set the context so the callback function knows where to do work
                            // the context will be the clicked <a> element
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              //set the parent li to inactive
              var parentListItem = $(this).parents("li"),
                  statusDiv = $(this).parents("li").find("div.status");
              if (parentListItem.hasClass("active")) {
                  parentListItem.removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
                  statusDiv.text("halted");
                  $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Icons-mini-action_go.gif");
              } else {
                  parentListItem.removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
                  statusDiv.text("running");
                  $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Icons-mini-action_stop.gif");
              }
          },
          error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){alert(strError);
    }
    });
    });
});
```

There were a few changes here.
- I set the context in your `$.ajax` call to the `<a>` being clicked so we could work with the `<li>` item in order to modify the contents.  I'm assuming that you may have multiple `<li>` elements, so we need to make sure to modify only the one that's clicked -- not all at once.  :)  In the linked jsFiddle script, I have several `<li>` items, and only the one that gets clicked will get updated.
- I don't have separate scripts based on class -- I set the class based upon what the class currently is, assuming there's only 2 states (running/halted).  If you have more, the logic will change, but hopefully this gets you started.
- I don't rebuild the image link -- I just adjust the `src` attribute and other classes based on the click.

Other than those changes, that should do it.  Let me know if there are questions and I'll update my answer accordingly.

I hope this helps!

BTW - the jsFiddle script calls a jsFiddle test ajax service.  It waits 2 seconds before returning, and basically just sends back what you sent it.  I did this just to simulate an ajax call.  It's just a junk call that I put in.  Just wanted to mention that in case you were wondering about that.  Thx.

Comment: Thank you veeerry much ! I can't tell you how much this helped me.
The li.class change works fine as well as the other class change. Now I have another problem; i may have some VPS that are in 'inactive' state at the beginning (you assumed they were only in active state) so i simply duplicated the jquery code and added inactive class trigger; now the problem is that I cannot get the browser to 'find out' that the class has changed, it's still in 'active' state whenever i see the class change in firebug. any idea ?